# Reasons why the scheduler isn't running a command in a controller every day?

Tags: php, laravel

I've encountered a very strange problem that has only started to happen since I reset the server (Ubuntu).

I have a method that is called every day

```
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\CronController@updateTasks')->daily()->timezone('Europe/London')->at('12:00');
```

but it is no longer working. It seems to have stopped ever since I reset the server but I can't confirm that.

However, what is strange is that I also have the following code

```
$schedule->call(function () {


  //Code here

})->daily()->timezone('Europe/London')->at('12:00');
```

and yet it works perfectly.

Any idea what has caused this problem?

Comment: Have you added the scheduler command as a cron job?

Comment: Yes the scheduler works fine. All "inline" scheduled commands that are implemented within the kernel.php file work completely ok. The problem arises when the scheduler tries to run a method located in a controller. It's been working perfectly for months until Saturday.

Comment: Does it throw any error?

Comment: Nope. Just found something interesting. If I change the time to 12:01, then it works fine. Is it possible that something above the call to the method is causing an error and the rest of the functions following it do not run? Does the scheduler work like that or will it continue to the next scheduled function even after an error? I have multiple calls at 12pm so perhaps one of them has went rogue.

Comment: However I've just manually checked each function/method and they all work fine. Is it possible that it's taking too long to reach `$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\CronController@updateTasks')->daily()->timezone('Europe/London')->at('12:00');` and by that time, it isn't 12:00? This call is located at the very end of kernel.php.

Comment: No, for what I know, the scheduler doesn't create synchronous tasks... It's for sure a time / timezone problem (otherwise it would not perform the task either at 12:00 or 12:01)

Comment: *EDIT*: from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/scheduling#background-tasks) _By default, multiple commands scheduled at the same time will execute sequentially._ So it may be a time elapsed problem... The best solution it's to avoid the callback, create jobs and enque them